# The revision of a specific branch(within another branch) within SVN - Using SVNKit

Tags: java, svn, svnkit

I am trying to get the latest revision from a folder within a branch on svn. The problem is when I do

```
repository.getLatestRevision(); //with url of the folder: /svn/home/test/foldertest/scripts
```

I do not get the correct revision of the folder, but I get the latest revision from the `url: "svn/home".`

I hope I'm being clear enough.

I'm using SVNKit as library for this java application.

What could be the problem?

Comment: AFAIK, You need to look at the history to find the last time the directory changed.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like [this is what you need](http://old.nabble.com/getting-a-directory%27s-latest-revision-number-td17441178.html).